# How to read names with space?

Tags: c++, input

If I have the data look like this:

```
Michael 30
Tom 35
```

I can handle it by the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()  {
    std::string name;
    int age;
    while(std::cin >> name >> age)  {
        std::cout << name << " is " << age << " years old." << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However if my data looks like this:

```
Michael Corleone
30
Tom Hagen
35
```

I tried using this code, **but it only read the first line**, the logic seems that it should read all the lines, so I don't know why this attempt fails.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()  {
    std::string name;
    int age;
    while(std::getline(std::cin, name) && std::cin >> age)  {
        std::cout << name << " is " << age << " years old." << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Even worse, if my data look like this:

```
Michael Corleone 30
Tom Hagen 35
```

Follow the suggestion by one of the answers, I can have a workaround by splitting the name into `name1` and `name2`:

```
int main()  {
    std::string name1, name2;
    int age;
    while(std::cin >> name1 >> name2 >> age)  {
        std::cout << name1 + ' ' + name2 
            << " is " << age << " years old." << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**However, this is not nice, what if someone have a middle name for example?**

Comment: @TimSeguine why so offensive?

Comment: One question per question please.  Which input method do you actually need to read in?

Comment: @TimSeguine even if this is a homework, the user has tried something so no offense.

Comment: @TimSeguine It's not the act of asking a question that's offensive, it's how you put it that could make it sound like it is.

Comment: @osuka_ How should I have asked it then in your opinion, given that I wanted to discover if the question was a homework problem? I can assure you that no offense was meant. Hell, I even upvoted this question. I know of no other way in the English language(despite being a native speaker) to discover if something is homework than to ask exactly the words "Is this homework?" And to be clear. What I wrote doesn't "sound like" anything. It is text. If it "sounded" like I intended it a certain way, that is your fault not mine.

Comment: I think I misunderstood it, since in some other forums posting a homework question is always being frown upon...

Comment: @TimSeguine Maybe spell out "I mean no offense" or something along those lines? I don't know, honestly - I didn't feel like you were harsh or anything, and just meant to present the other side of the argument. But let's go listen to some music :)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the second example with this data:

```
Michael Corleone
30
Tom Hagen
35
```

The problem is that after reading the `age` with `std::cin >> age` the end-of-line character is still left in the stream so the following `std::getline` gets nothing because it thinks the line is empty (which it is).

The trick is to skip whitespace before reading each new record:

```
std::string name;
int age;
while(std::cin >> std::ws && std::getline(std::cin, name) && std::cin >> age) {
    std::cout << name << " is " << age << " years old." << std::endl;
}
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
std::string name;
int age;
while(std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, name) >> age) {
    std::cout << name << " is " << age << " years old." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Your explanation is clear enough, but how about the third data case?

Comment: @buzhidao That's always going to be more tricky. There is a bunch of ways to solve that. I would be tempted to read in the data one whole line at a time and then, for each line, use [std::string::rfind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind) to locate the space before the end number and divide the line there.

Answer (score -3):

How about this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
    int main()  {
        std::string firstname;
        std::string lastname;
        int age;
        while(true){
          std::cin >> firstname;
          std::cin >> lastname;
          std::cin >> age);
          std::cout << firstname << " " << lastname << " is " << age << " years old." << std::endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? The OP did not say that the file he's reading in from(or the console) would contain anything but names and ages.

Comment: `std::getline(std::cin, firstname);` is going to read the entire line so it has the first and last name in it, then the next call reads the `int` and then the reading breaks there.

Comment: Ok, edited. And yes, it will end when there is no more input

Comment: No it will not.  `while(true)` will run forever.

Comment: OP did not specify how many names to read in. How should I know when to stop the loop? Get serious

Comment: The problem is that he will never be able to stop inputting the data.  If you are going to give someone a solution, it should work.  This does not.