# Reading from cin doesn't return entire input string

Tags: c++

I have to prompt the user to enter their name and their height using two separate inputs, one for feet and one for inches. Then I have to display what they entered. Ex: Name, you are x feet y inches tall. The program I wrote runs but it's not working as intended. After I write an input for the first question which is the name, the program skips the other questions and ends the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int name;
    int f;
    int i; 
    // Start: Enter Name
    cout << "What is your name?" << endl;
    cin >> name; 
    // Enter height 
    cout << "How many feet tall are you tall?" << endl;
    cin >> f;
    // Enter inches
    cout << "How many inches tall are you after feet?" << endl;
    cin >> i;
    // End: All info entered
    cout << name << " you are " << (f) << " feet " << (i) << " inches tall." << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remember that with `cin >> name;` you can only enter the first name. If you enter a space the  part after will go to the next cin

Comment: You also don't close out your program. Missing the brace for int main at the end.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39881604/how-to-read-names-with-space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39881604/how-to-read-names-with-space)

Comment: I assume the missing `}` is a typo

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `std::string name;` as the name variable?

Comment: Agreed, an `int` is going to work for a name. Unless you expect people to answer with a number

Comment: If you number everyone and keep the population under (typically) 2.2 billion you could have a go of using `int`

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for all your help.  I finally got it working the way I wanted to.

Answer (score 3):

First and most importantly, you should change the type of `name` from `int` to `string`. Your current program tries to read your input to `name` as a number and not text.

Now, if your program is still not working as intended, make sure when you are typing in input for `name` there is no white-space (spaces, tabs, etc.) in between the name you are trying to input. For example, the input of `John` would be fine, but `John Smith` would not. This is because the `>>` operator when used with `cin` values all white-space the same. This means that pressing the space bar is the same as pressing the enter key to your program. If you are trying to input a full name, look into using [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) to read input up until the enter key is pressed.

Getline Example:

```
cout << "What is your name?";
getline (std::cin,name);
```

**Summary**:
Change `int name;` to `string name;`. If you need to read multiple words for the name use [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/).